# How to count number of lines in a file in C?

Tags: c

I have a function that is supposed to count the number of lines in a file inputted by the user.  However, whenever I input a file my function keeps returning 0 lines.

```
int findnum_lines(FILE* fp){

  int num_lines = 0;
  char line;
  int size;

  size = ftell(fp);
  line = getc(fp);
  if(size != 0){
    while(line != EOF){
      if(line == '\n'){
        num_lines = num_lines + 1;
      }
      line = getc(fp);
    }
  } else {
    num_lines = 0;
  }
  printf("%d", num_lines);
  return num_lines;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char** lines = NULL;
    int num_lines = 0;
    FILE* fp = validate_input(argc, argv);

    num_lines = findnum_lines(fp);
    read_lines(fp, &lines, &num_lines);
    print_lines(lines, num_lines);
    free_lines(lines, num_lines);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

My example file is:

```
Hello Class
This is what I would call a normal file
It isn't very special
But it still is important
```

So my function should return 4 lines, not 0.

UPDATED:

```
int findnum_lines(FILE* fp){

  int num_lines = 0;
  int line;

  line = getc(fp);

  while(line != EOF){
    if(line == '\n'){
      num_lines = num_lines + 1;
      }
    line = getc(fp);
    }
  printf("%d", num_lines);
  return num_lines;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char** lines = NULL;
    int num_lines = 0;
    FILE* fp = validate_input(argc, argv);

    num_lines = findnum_lines(fp);
    read_lines(fp, &lines, &num_lines);
    print_lines(lines, num_lines);
    free_lines(lines, num_lines);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

With this updated code no num_lines is printed.

Comment: Shouldn't `'n'` be `'\n'`, although the absence of the letter `n` in a text file is an oddity in itself.

Comment: You are counting the occurrences of the character `'n'`, not `'\n'` which is the escape sequence for a line break

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I would have answered if I was confident this was the *only* issue.

Comment: @Bathsheba: sorry that was a typo! I fixed it but my function still returns 0.

Comment: @Christina are you sure you was able to open the file ? print an error if _fp_ is NULL, currently there is no check about that

Comment: @bruno I do check for that in my validate_input() function in main().

Comment: @Christina so I suppose you `exit(<n>)` in case of error because, again, you get the result of `validate_input` as a FILE * without visible test and continue the execution

Comment: “Nothing is returned” does not make sense. A function that has a non-void return type returns a value, unless it terminates its execution in an abnormal way (such as program execute or a `longjmp`, neither of which appears in the source code). Do you mean nothing is printed? In any case, this is a different question, so, if you want to ask it, you should post it as a new question, with a [mcve].

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for letting me know! I will post it as another question.

Comment: Christina is the file consisted of only 3 characters `"abc"`, would you consider that a file of 1 or 0 lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ftell` reports the current position in the file. For a file that has just been opened, the position is the start, and `ftell` returns zero. Then, since `size` is zero, the loop in `findnum_lines` processes zero characters and reports no lines were found.

Generally, you do not want to get the file size and then loop on that. One reason is that the file can change while you read it—other processes may write more data to it or may truncate it. Another reason is that it is unnecessary. Just read characters until you get `EOF`, using a `while` loop (or a `do … while` loop).

Additionally, `char line;` should be `int line;` because it is used to hold the result of `getc`, which may be either a character or `EOF`, and a `char` is inadequate to hold `EOF`. (Also, `getc` returns the character’s value as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int`, so, in an implementation where `char` is signed, `char` cannot even properly represent all characters.)

Answer (score 1):

One problem is the call to `ftell()` is done with the file offset still at zero:

```
int findnum_lines(FILE* fp){

  int num_lines = 0;
  int line; // changed char to int
  int size;

  size = ftell(fp);
  line = getc(fp);
  if(size != 0){
    while(line != EOF){
      if(line == '\n'){
        num_lines = num_lines + 1;
      }
      line = getc(fp);
    }
  } else {
    num_lines = 0;
  }
  printf("%d", num_lines);
  return num_lines;
}
```

If `findnum_lines()` is called right after the file is opened, the file's current offset returned by `ftell()` will be at the start of the file - or zero.

So `num_lines` is set to zero, and zero is returned.

Note that checking the file size is not needed - since you're counting newline characters - `'\n'` - a zero length file will have zero newline characters in it to count.